# Visual studio team explorer shows red cross in build en reports folder

Tags: visual-studio-2008, explorer

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Some facts:

-The direct report link works(i can surf to http://theserver/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=/someSite )

-I have enough rights

-It has worked and suddenly it stopped working

-I can open source control

-I am directly connected over a local lan with the tfs server

-My colleages do not have any issues like that

[TFSproblem http://img178.imageshack.us/img178/5871/tfsproble.jpg](http://img178.imageshack.us/img178/5871/tfsproble.jpg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into this a while back and found my solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/tfssetup/thread/07a54abf-3c48-492f-bda6-53e7dce1d8d1/).  The solution is described by "Fern82" near the bottom of the thread.

What you need to do is delete the following directory:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<Current User>\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Team Foundation\1.0
```

Next run the following statement in a Visual Studio Command Prompt:

```
devenv /resetuserdata
```

Comment: it also fixed a bunch of other problems and increased visual studio performance a lot. thx again!

Comment: Not in a Visual Studio, Execute this command line: Start > Run : “devenv /resetuserdata".

Answer (score 1):

Search the following link for complete solution:

Issue: Red cross on reports folder and New TFS Team project creation error: TF30004, TF30171, TF300224

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsadmin/thread/27eca9a3-39e1-45ce-8f3c-8af8ede006c6

Arun Sangal

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and an apparently separate issue with not being able to publish. I found the solution to the problem with publishing and it also fixed my TFS woes!

This might work for you. Open up a command prompt and run the following, depending on your version of Windows.

regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll"

regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll"

This re-registers an internet explorer dll that is used by Visual Studio.